# Conversion of HTML to Jade

Tags: html

How do I to write HTML code in Jade?

```html
<div class="profile-env">
   <section class="profile-info-tabs">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" data-collapsed="0">
           `enter code here`
           <div class="panel-body">
              <h2>University Admins <span><a href="add-admin.html" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
                 <i class="entypo-user-add"></i>
                 ADD Admin
                 </a></span>
              </h2>
              <br />
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
   </section>
</div>
```

Please help me before I throw this computer out of the window.

Comment: why the computer has to suffer for your idiocracy :P ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a online conversor like this: http://html2jade.org/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's called pug now, check this out for some basics;
https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-pug-template-engine-e49cfa291e33

```html
.profile-env
  section.profile-info-tabs
    .row
      .col-md-12
        .panel.panel-primary(data-collapsed='0')
          | `enter code here`
          .panel-body
            h2
              | University Admins 
              span
                a.btn.btn-default.pull-right(href='add-admin.html')
                  i.entypo-user-add
                  |            ADD Admin
            br
```